# Why I am not getting True when testing equation?

Tags: equation-solving, logic

My input is:

$ \frac{1}{a^x}==(\frac{1}{a})^x $

I want to get output:

```
True
```

But getting output:

$ a^{-x}==\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^x $

**Question:** How to get output: `True`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your expression is only true if `a` is positive.

```
Simplify[a^-x == (1/a)^x, a > 0]
```

> `True`

Comment: Is there a way to ask Mathematica in which cases it is true and in which not? So instead of me specifing for cases when `a > 0`, Mathematica will give me all possible cases with corresponding `TRUE/False` values.

Comment: @vasili111 That is an excellent, yet different question. I strongly suggest asking it as a separate question!

Comment: @rubenvb Done: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210131/is-there-simplest-and-universal-way-to-ask-mathematica-to-give-you-in-which-case

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) to find out the ratio in general:

```
PowerExpand[(1/a)^x a^x, Assumptions->True]
```

> E^(2 I π x Floor[1/2 + Arg[a]/(2 π)])

For generic `x` this expression is only 1 when

```
Floor[1/2+Arg[a]/(2 π)] == 0
```

Using [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) gives:

```
Reduce[Floor[1/2 + Arg[a]/(2 π)] == 0, a, Complexes]
```

> (Im[a] != 0 && Re[a] < 0) || Re[a] >= 0

So the equality is only untrue for negative reals (i.e., along the branch cut for logs and powers).

Check with [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify):

```
Simplify[a^-x == (1/a)^x, (Im[a] != 0 && Re[a] < 0) || Re[a] >= 0]
```

> True

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.