# Is there simplest and universal way to ask Mathematica to give you in which cases it is True and in which False?

Tags: equation-solving, logic

This question emerged from [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210057/why-i-am-not-getting-true-when-testing-equation/210059?noredirect=1#comment538648_210059).

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/210062/11639) answer explains how to do that with particular equation with several steps but I am interested if there exists more simple and universal method to just provide Mathematica any equation and Mathematica returns in which cases the equation is `True` and in which cases `False`?

Comment: `Reduce` is in general a good start.

Comment: This is not a complete, stand-alone question.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau As you see from the link I have provided many people are interested in this question. Can you please improve this question by editing it so, that it ask same question and is complete. Thank you.

Comment: It should have an explicit example (and not an image, I will add). Also an explanation or example to indicate how the function `Reduce` falls short of what is wanted.